# Headers using struct and enums in each other?

Tags: c, struct, enums, header-files

So I'm converting my code to a new structure that uses header files (I should note that I don't often use them) and I'm having trouble getting it to compile (using gcc --std=c11). I think I know what the issue is, I just don't know how to implement the code to fix it.

Here's some code that discribes the problem.

main.c

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
#include "header.h"

int main( )
{
    BigStruct bigStruct;

    DoStuff( &bigStruct );
    OtherStuff( &bigStruct );

    return 0;
}
```

file1.h

```
#ifndef FILE1_H
#define FILE1_H

#include "header.h"

typedef enum TagMyEnum
{
    MY_THING1,
    MY_THING2,

    MY_ENUM_END
}
MyEnum;

typedef struct TagMyStruct
{
    // Variables.
}
MyStruct;

typedef struct TagBigStruct BigStruct;

void DoStuff( BigStruct *bigStruct );

#endif
```

file2.h

```
#ifndef FILE2_H
#define FILE2_H

#include "header.h"

typedef enum TagOtherEnum
{
    OTHER_THING1,
    OTHER_THING2,

    OTHER_ENUM_END
}
OtherEnum;

typedef struct TagOtherStruct
{
    // Variables.
}
OtherStruct;

typedef struct TagBigStruct BigStruct;

void OtherStuff( BigStruct *bigStruct );

#endif
```

header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

typedef struct TagMyStruct MyStruct;
typedef struct TagOtherStruct OtherStruct;

typedef struct TagBigStruct
{
    MyStruct myStruct[MY_ENUM_END];
    OtherStruct otherStruct[OTHER_ENUM_END];
}
BigStruct;

#endif
```

The compiler is telling me this.

```
In file included from file1.h:4:0,
                 from main.c:2:
header.h:12:23: error: ‘MY_ENUM_END’ undeclared here (not in a function)
     MyStruct myStruct[MY_ENUM_END];
```

Now I think I understand the error, I just don't know how to implement a solution.

Answer (score 1):

`Header.h` needs `MY_ENUM_END` but is is included before the definition of `MyEnum` in `file1.h`

This is call circular dependency

Easy fix

```
#ifndef FILE1_H
#define FILE1_H

typedef enum TagMyEnum
{
    MY_THING1,
    MY_THING2,

    MY_ENUM_END
}
MyEnum;

#include "header.h"

// ...
```

Same thing for file2.h.

Best to redesign your headers to avoid cross references between them.

Comment: A less easy, but more correct fix would be to get rid of this awful dependency between the 3 files. Either unite them, or properly separate them.

Comment: Thanks. I removed #include "header.h" from file1.h and file2.h, and that fixed the problem too. Is this a better solution or more elegant?

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, sure. I was writing that in the while.

Comment: @TomSmale - Why was it included to begin with? Headers should only be included if the code cannot compile without them. They aren't meant to be included willy-nilly just because.